Altered product operation on power series
Suppose you have two power series $A(x)=\sum_n a_nx^n$ and $B(x)=\sum_n b_nx^n$ over, say, the integers. I have reason to care about the product
$$(A*B)(x):=\sum_n a_nB(x^n)=\sum_{n,m}a_nb_mx^{nm}.$$
This is different to standard multiplication, where $x^{nm}$ is replaced with $x^{n+m}$.
Does anybody have information on this product? I originally thought it was related to plethystic substitution but that seems not to be the case.
Thanks!

This should be related to the ring of formal power series in infinitely many variables, one for each prime. Basically, because $p^a p^b = p^{a+b}$.

I can see this perspective, where each $x^n$ is treated as a separate variable and I simply impose the relation $x^nx^m=x^{n+m}$. Then I get the standard product, but it feels like some structure is lost ...

Are you sure you don't want to use $a(s):=\sum_na_nn^{-s}$ instead of $A(x)$? After all, $m^{-s}n^{-s}=(mn)^{-s}$ (for a suitable range of $s$ and a choice of branch).

This is strongly related to the convolution $*$  of arithmetic
functions $f,g\colon \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by $(f*g)(n):=\sum_{d|n}f(d)g(\frac{n}{d})$.
(Remark: Since editing of comments is very cumbersome when formulas are involved, I decided to give an answer rather than writing a comment.)

I have now realised this is just convolution under multiplication, since
$$[x^n](A*B)(x)=\sum_{m\mid n}a_mb_{n/m}$$
